# itrate on a dictionary from a list with dictionary name

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

i am trying to iterate on a list were the variables in the list are dictionary names and then iterate on the keys in these dictionary 
my code is like this :

```
IA = {"V":"CVolt","T":"CTemp"}
CLR = {"V":"CLR_Volt","T":"CLR_Temp"}
GT = {"V":"GT_CVolt","T":"GT_Temp"}
PP = ["IA","GT","CLR"]
AFT = {"IA":0,"GT":0,"CLR":0}
AFV = {"IA":0,"GT":0,"CLR":0}
Voltage=0
Vs ={"IA":0.85,"GT":0.85,"CLR":0.85}
Tempreture = 0
Ts ={"IA":30,"GT":30,"CLR":30}
EAK = 7e3
Stress = {"IA":0,"GT":0,"CLR":0}
C = 1
Seff={"IA":0,"GT":0,"CLR":0}
csv.DictReader
with open(File,"r+") as Fin:
    reader = csv.DictReader(Fin, dialect='excel')
    for line in reader:
        for i in PP:
            AFT[i] = math.exp(EAK*((1/Ts[i])-(1/float(line[i["T"]]))))
            AFV[i] = math.exp(float(line[i["T"]])-Vs[i])
            Stress[i] = AFT[i] * AFV[i]
            Seff[i] = Seff[i]+Stress[i]
```

my problem is how do i get the value of the Key in dictionary i

```
AFT[i] = math.exp(EAK*((1/Ts[i])-(1/float(line[i["T"]]))))
```

in this case at the first loop i would like to get line["CTemp"]

any suggestions or different approach is welcome

Answer (score 1):

you can either use python's built in [locals()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) function:

```
>>> IA = {"V":"CVolt","T":"CTemp"}
>>> locals()['IA']
{'T': 'CTemp', 'V': 'CVolt'}
>>> locals()['IA']['T']
'CTemp'
```

or better, have your variables in one big dict like that:

```
>>> vars = {
    'IA': {"V":"CVolt","T":"CTemp"},
    'CLR': {"V":"CLR_Volt","T":"CLR_Temp"},
    ...
}
>>> vars['IA']
{'T': 'CTemp', 'V': 'CVolt'}
>>> vars['IA']['T']
'CTemp'
```

Thanks @damienfrancois to complete the answer with locals:

```
math.exp(EAK*((1/Ts[i])-(1/float(line[locals()[i]['T']]))))
```

with vars dict:

```
math.exp(EAK*((1/Ts[i])-(1/float(line[vars[i]['T']]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this

```
AFT[i] = math.exp(EAK*((1/Ts[i])-(1/float(line[eval(i)["T"]]))))
```

Note the use of `eval` to transform the string `IA` into the object named `IA`.

The use of `locals()`, or of a container dict is probably better though; see @Guy's answer.